# How to display result of SQL in alert message using javascript in jsp?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Below is COUNT SQL statement in jsp. As you can see my dropdown of studentlevel will display the count of each level. If a user clicks on one of the dropdowns, then if the studentlevel achieved the maximum number of 5 people the system will produce an alert message but I failed to do so. I think my method is wrong. Please help me to make it happen.

```
  <%

try{

        Connection conn = connectionManager.getConnection();

        String searchQuery = "Select count(studentlevel) AS COUNTER1 FROM student WHERE studentlevel = '1'";
        OraclePreparedStatement pst = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(searchQuery);
        OracleResultSet rs = (OracleResultSet) pst.executeQuery();

        String searchQuery2 = "Select count(studentlevel) AS COUNTER2 FROM student WHERE studentlevel = '2'";
        OraclePreparedStatement pst2 = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(searchQuery2);
        OracleResultSet rs2 = (OracleResultSet) pst2.executeQuery();

        String searchQuery3 = "Select count(studentlevel) AS COUNTER3 FROM student WHERE studentlevel = '3'";
        OraclePreparedStatement pst3 = (OraclePreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement(searchQuery3);
        OracleResultSet rs3 = (OracleResultSet) pst3.executeQuery();
%>

<div class="select-wrapper">Student Level:
                                    <select name="studentlevel" id="studentlevel" required>
                                            <option value="">- Student Level -</option>
<%  

                                                while(rs3.next()){

                                                    System.out.println("The sql : "+searchQuery3);                      
                                                    count3 = rs3.getString(1);

                                            %>
                                            <option value="3">3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<%= count3 %>/5]</option>
                                            <p id="message5"></p>
                                            <%} %>
                                            <%  

                                                while(rs2.next()){

                                                    System.out.println("The sql : "+searchQuery2);                      
                                                    count2 = rs2.getString(1);

                                            %>
                                            <option value="2">2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<%= count2 %>/5]</option>
<p id="message6"></p>                                               
<%} %>
                                            <%  

                                                while(rs.next()){

                                                    System.out.println("The sql : "+searchQuery);                       
                                                    count1 = rs.getString(1);

                                            %>
                                            <option value="1">1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[<%= count1 %>/5]</option>
<p id="message7"></p>                                               
<%} %>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
var c, d, e, text5, text 6, text7;
c = document.getElementById("count3").value;
d = document.getElementById("count2").value;
e = document.getElementById("count1").value;
if(c>0 || c<=5)
{
text5 = "The Class is Already Full, Please Contact the Clerk for Futher Information.";
}
else
    {text5= "";
    }

if(d>0 || d<=5)
{
text6 = "The Class is Already Full, Please Contact the Clerk for Futher Information.";
}
else
    {text6= "";
    }

if(e>0 || e<=5)
{
text7 = "The Class is Already Full, Please Contact the Clerk for Futher Information.";
}
else
    {text7= "";
    }
document.getElementById("message5").innerHTML = text5;
document.getElementById("message6").innerHTML = text6;
document.getElementById("message7").innerHTML = text7;
</script>
```